# How to remove specific string from string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string in my code. I want to remove `Window: String` from below string using regular expression.

```
"function(param: Int, Window: String, param1: String, Window: String)"
```

It should be like

```
"function(param: Int, param1: String)"
```

and if it is `"function(Window: String)"` then it should be `"function()"`

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```js
let str = 'function(param: Int, Window: String, param1: String, Window: String)';

console.log(str.replace(/(, )?Window: String/g, ''));
```

Comment: It is working but if `function(Window: String)` like then it is not working. It should `function()`

Comment: If my string is `let str = 'function(Window: String, param: Int, Window: String, param1: String, Window: String)';

console.log(str.replace(/(, )?Window: String/g, ''));` then it is giving me this `function(, param: Int, param1: String)` it should be `function(param: Int, param1: String)`